# Creating comma separated string from numeric values with multiple formats

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-formatting, stringbuilder

I am creating a string with a list of comma separated values, but these numeric values have different formats. Currently I am using something like this:

```
var values = new StringBuilder();
// These are all of type double
values.AppendFormat("{0:F1},", aLength);
values.AppendFormat("{0:F4},", anAngle);
values.AppendFormat("{0:F1},", aHeight);
values.AppendFormat("{0:F2},{1:F2},", a2DPoint.X, a2DPoint.Y);
// while these are all of type int
values.Append(anID).Append(",");
values.Append(anInt).Append(",");
values.Append(anotherInt);
if (aListOfInt.Count > 0)
{
    values.Append(",");
    values.Append(String.Join(",", aListOfInt));
}

var resultString = values.ToString();
```

Is this the right way? I could do this also with [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), creating beforehand a `List<string>` similar to the `StringBuilder values` above, but would it better?
Is there a more elegant way?

Note: I am new to C#

Comment: Using comma-separated strings for decimal numbers is a bad idea - there's a lot of cultures that use a comma in their numbers, and it's a frequent cause of trouble. For example, a comma might be used to separate thousands, or even instead of the decimal point. At least use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when converting to and from string, otherwise you've just broken your application for half the planet :)

Comment: @Luaan Ah, that is a good point. In this particular case, this is information that is being written to a file, for backwards compatibility with an old system, which was even written in a different language. We are trying to change the way things are done.  But your comment is something that we should definitely consider. Thanks for that.

Comment: I think the best way to implement this is to create a class for each measurement unit (i.e. Length, Angle, Point) and override their ToString methods and let polymorphism to the work for you. As for joining the values, string.Join is the cleanest option.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, CSV is quite a common format.  However when creating CSV you should use `InvariantCulture` as Luaan said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does it quite nicely:

```
var resultString = String.Join(",", new []
{
    aLength.ToString("F1"),
    anAngle.ToString("F4"),
    aHeight.ToString("F1"),
    a2DPoint.X.ToString("F2"),
    a2DPoint.Y.ToString("F2"),
    anID.ToString(),
    anInt.ToString(),
    anotherInt.ToString(),
}.Concat(aListOfInt.Select(x => x.ToString())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var objList = new List<object>();
objList.Add(1);
objList.Add(2.0);
...
var resultString = string.Join(",", objList.Cast<string>());
```

Put your values in a list of objects, cast the values to string, and join the values.

But with the above you will loose your formatting.
I have another solution for. I think this is a short syntax without loosing the format of each value:

```
var stringList = new List<string>{
    aLength.ToString("F1"),
    anAngle.ToString("F4"),
    ...
};
var resultString = string.Join(",", stringList);
```

Comment: How exactly would that help with the different formats of the values? I.e. some with `F1` others with `F2` still others with `F4` and so on?

Comment: See the second section. I saw my mistake in the same moment. First I thought you mean the mix of double and int.

Comment: @MathiasMüller your second section is what I was referring to when I said "I could do this also with `String.Join`", instead of building a `StringBuilder` list, building a `List<string>` and using `String.Join`. But is it better than what I did above? As I am new to C# I keep having all these doubts about what is the better way to do things--more C#-like, more elegant, more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is more elegant (rather than optimal), you might try something like this:

```
//Note the commas in the formats,and that formats and data have the same size.
List<string> formats = new List<string>(new string[] {"{0:F1},", "{0:F4},", "{0:F2},",{0}});
List<object> data=new List<object>(new object[]{4,2,0.12,new object()});
StringBuilder resultBuilder=new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       resultBuilder.AppendFormat(formats[i], data[i]);
 }
string result = resultBuilder.ToString();
```

As long as you're careful about how you set up your formats and data, you shouldn't have to do any other processing other than the for loop to "zip" them together. I'd suggest overriding ToString() on whatever class a2DPoint is, so you can shove it into a single format block rather than having special handling, or splitting up a2DPoint.X and a2DPoint.Y into separate data/format blocks. It's not the most efficient way to do it, though. The Lists take up room and time; Arrays would probably be better if you  know ahead of time how many entries you'll have.

Edit: Example of method in comments
Edit: Adding example of method referred to in comments:

```
public class FormatZipper {
    //This could be two lists, but it's probably more space/time efficent to use a single list. 
    List<Tuple<string,object>> _entries;
    StringBuilder _builder;
    public FormatZipper() {
        _builder = new StringBuilder();
        _entries = new List<Tuple<string, object>>();
    }
    public void AddEntry(string fmt, object data) {
        _entries.Add(Tuple.Create(fmt, data));
    }

    public string CurrentString {
        get {
            _builder.Clear();
            foreach (var entry in _entries) {
                _builder.AppendFormat(entry.Item1, entry.Item2);
            }
            return _builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        FormatZipper zipper = new FormatZipper();
        zipper.AddEntry("{0:F1},", 1);
        Console.WriteLine(zipper.CurrentString);
        zipper.AddEntry("{0:F2,", 1);
        Console.WriteLine(zipper.CurrentString);


    }
}
```

Comment: Even though it looks interesting, the problem with this solution is that, as you said, you need to be very careful setting up your formats and data, otherwise it is very easy to get a mismatch.

Comment: You could fix that by warping both lists into a single class that only allows adding a value and a format at the same time, i.e. formatZipper.AddField(string fmt,object data). Then you'd run the for loop on request either by overriding ToString() or providing some sort of  method or property. There are more sophisticated ways of doing this, but they require a lot more knowledge about the specifics.

Comment: I do appreciate your effort, but isn't it starting to look a bit convoluted? In any case, I like your idea of the two lists.

Comment: @alondono It depends on where you want to see your complexity, and what exactly you're trying to accomplish. If you don't know what format blocks you need ahead of time, doing any significant optimization is going to be difficult. You're probably best off with the `StringBuilder.AppendFormat()` calls, and reusing the StringBuilder to save some time. If you know what data your string needs ahead of time, you're actually probably better off with one big String.Format call.

Comment: @alondono What I made was something that allows you to get partial strings, and (assuming you wrote the functions yourself) add, remove, or reorder fields at any point with a minimum of hassle,which is something iv'e found useful in the past. Like I said, without knowing more about what exactly you're doing, it's very hard to know what the "best" way to do something is.